# Can't find where is the Euro symbol set in Magento 1.3.2.3

Tags: magento, locale, euro

Weird but I can't find where is € symbol set in Magento 1.3.2.3. My locale is German, so I checked /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/de.xml, but for Euro it only have the following code:

```
        <currency type="EUR">
            <displayName>Euro</displayName>
            <displayName count="other">Euro</displayName>
        </currency>
```

However at the front-end the € symbol is displayed. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into lib/Zend/Locale/Data/characters.xml
There you'll find wich characters are used to replace the definitions.

For example:

```
<currency type="EUR">
```

Type EUR will be replaced for the € symbol.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the **Currency.php** class under **app/code/Core/Mage/Directory/Model**, you will find that Magento uses the **Zend_Currency** class which in turn uses the **Zend_Locale_Data** to retrieve currency symbol.

Hope it helps.
Regards, Alessandro

Comment: And Zend_Locale_Data is looking into /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/de.xml for currency symbol which is not there. We are going circles :-|